# Javascript create an array of place categories

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create an array of categories from an array of objects called places, what i'm doing:

```
            this.places.forEach((p) => {
                p.categories.forEach((c) => {
                    if(!this.categories.some(c.id)) {
                        this.categories.push(c)
                    }
                })
            })
```

I have an empty array where the categories are pushed, it is possible that places can have same categories so i want to check if the category already exists in the array so it won't get pushed inside the array. The method above doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
this.places.forEach((p) => {
                p.categories.forEach((c) => {
                    if(!this.categories.includes(c)) {
                        this.categories.push(c)
                    }
                })
            })
```

Didn't work as well, any solution would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didnt provide a strict enough condition for your categories check.

`this.categories.some(cat => cat.id === c.id)`

`.includes` is for basic types only.

```
this.places.forEach((p) => {
                p.categories.forEach((c) => {
                    if(!this.categories.find(cat => cat.id === c.id)) {
                        this.categories.push(c)
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: Great answer on the whole! One small nit: *"You didnt provide a condition for your categories check"* They did, it was just incorrect. :-) `.some(c.id)` is a condition, but it checks `c.id` against the *objects* in the `categories` array. Your change fixes it by using `.find` so you can compare the `id` property of each category object to `c.id` rather than the category object.